# Laravel routes order

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes

I have set a few routes in my routes/web.php file in Laravel 5, but I need all the others routes will be using a "RouterController". Can I use something like this?

```
Route::get('/','HomeController@index');
Auth::Routes();
.
.
.
Route::get('/{slug}', 'RouterController@process');
```

It means, that in this occasion each route, which is not defined above, will be processed by RouterController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you are making a catchall route. The only issue with what you have is it will only match a route with a single segment:

```
yoursite.com/anything
```

but it will miss anything with more than 1 segment:

```
yoursite.com/anything/else/....
```

If you want to catch all you need a lil regex love to constrain the condition of the route parameter `slug`:

```
Route::get('{slug}', 'RouterController@process)->where('slug', '.*');
```

Now that route will catch anything URL.

There is also a `fallback` method on the router that will setup this route with the condition for you:

```
Route::fallback('yourAction');
```

Answer (score 0):

That is somewhat correct, it depends. You have the right idea. All routes will be handled by @process regardless of if they are defined or not depending on placement of the route in the route file.

If you wanted to handle undefined routes, you would have to place that /{slug} route at the very bottom of your routes file. This way, Laravel will first look to see if the route input is defined, and serve that route. And if it's not, then it will eventually make its way to /{slug}

I would not recommend using this approach though, it seems like bad practice to be honest. I think you're better off creating a view for resources/views/errors/404.blade.php and that way if a route is undefined, it is handled by the 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

What you think is right. Laravel checks the routes that you have defined in `web.php` from above to bottom, So every time you enter a route that doesn't exist in the routes you have defined above the last route, the entered route  `slug` would be passed to the `process()` function in `RouterController` and you can add your logic to this function to do what you want to do.